# CodedUITest in MVC5 hangs during Generate Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

I am learning how to do Coded UI testing, and I worked through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977233.aspx) tutorial without problems using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Unfortunately, that tutorial is a WPF project and I need to test an existing MVC5.2 web application.

For learning purposes, I created a new MVC5 web application, added a Coded UI test project to my solution, and set up a simple test of the log-in function. I am able to start the Coded UI Test Builder, and the Test Builder shows the steps when I click Show Recorded Steps. All good so far.

When I click Generate Code the Test Builder hangs with the Generating Code... progress bar repeating infinitely. I can break out of the loop by closing the Test Builder, but then I get nothing after answering Yes to "Do you want to close the Coded UI Test Builder and discard recorded actions?". Answering No continues the infinite loop.

Can anyone give me a hint where to find logs or output from this process to debug it? I'm stumped, and Google U hasn't helped me much today. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The log destination for the _test runs_ are set in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CodedUITestBuilder.exe.config file, under the UITestTraceFolder key. Unfortunately, this doesn't help solve the original question of why the Generate Code... hangs because this is the log for **running** the tests.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's late to answer this question but I found something that worked for me. When you are debugging your program Visual Studio doesn't allow you to change code. Generate Code tries to change the code while you are debugging the program thus hanging it. So I tried stopping the debugger and then pressing Generate Code. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I used the wrong namespace reference for CodedUITest. [This reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.aspx) says [CodedUITest] comes from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute, which I added to my development environment as a reference. This resolved the error and it appeared as if it worked, so I thought all was well until Generate Code hung.

I set up my test environment, and my code compiled and ran even though the [CodedUITest] annotation was red ("cannot resolve symbol CodedUITest"). I'm not sure why VS would allow that, but there it is. Once I located this problem, it was just a matter of researching where that annotation lived. Obviously, adding the above reference didn't work, so I kept digging.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652992/coded-ui-tests-cannot-resolve-symbol-uitesting); this gives all the correct references for Coded UI Testing.
The actual namespace is Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework. I removed the CodedUITestAttribute reference and added the CodedUITestFramework reference and the Generate Code worked as expected.

Comment: Worked yesterday, broken again today. Back to the drawing board! I'm pretty sure it's a reference sequencing issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you run CodedUI Test Builder from Visual Studio then launch your application from that same instance of Visual Studio it will also hang when trying to generate the code. For me I just launched the application independent of Visual Studio then the CodedUI Test Builder started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after updating Visual Studio Update 5, fix this issue.